# Datepicker UI-Bootstrap issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working with UI Bootstrap's datepicker and I some troubles.
The datepicker works fine, but calendar overflows from the sides.

In particular case look at this picture:

[image]

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.open2 = function() {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
};

$scope.popup2 = {
    opened: false
};
```

I have imported the following libraries(same order)

- bootstrap.min.css
- ui-bootstrap-csp.css
- angular.js
- angular-animate.js
- angular-touch.js
- ui-bootstrap.js
- ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

I'm missing something? Sorry for the basic problem, but i don't understand why the datepicker had this behavior.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then i don't think you have to use clicks to open the datepicker..

Comment: I took this code from getting started section of UI Bootstrap

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS apart from the UI Bootstrap? It's possible it accidentally overrides some UI Bootstrap styles. Disable it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes @bumpy, you are right! thanks so much for your help. i solved now!